# Is there anyway to make API requests click buttons (discord)

Tags: discord

I want to make an api request to the discord api to press a button component on a message

Comment: Trying to be able to make my discord client press buttons @Noah

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an API request that sends an interaction to discord: https://discord.com/api/v9/interactions
you can use

```
payload = {
        'message_id': message_id,
        'data': {'component_type': 2, 'custom_id': "page_end"}
    }
```

Message_id is the message that you want to send a button click to, component_type: 2 is the argument that tells that it wants to click a button (other component types would be 1, 3 etc)  and custom_id is the id of the button you want to click (you can find this information in the network section of dev tools).

Some buttons custom_id may be different each time with a bit at the end which is static. Not sure on how to get that yet but I will find out how